# Eclipse plugin to auto-fix "Double == Double" statements?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, double, equals

I'm developing a small API for personal use only, and it envolves A LOT of math. But, I just found that using "`double == double`", returns false.

So, my API uses a lot of these calculations, and I must re-write a lot of it. But, the API have for now 85,000 lines of code, so I think it would be a lot... problematic... re-writing it manually.

Is there any Eclipse plugin for auto-detecting these wrong statements and, if possible, fix them?

Thanks.

@Additional info:
I found this while testing some methods with all Number classes, and when I tested Doubles, here what I got:

```
Number of type 'class java.lang.Double':
  First value: 3.2
  Second value: 3.2

  first == second: false
  first != second: true
  second == first: false
  second != first: true
  first equals second: true
  second equals first: true
```

I ALWAYS used `Number` classes, almost never `raw primitives`. So now it's a big of a problem for me.

Comment: Can you add some code as an example?

Comment: Well, for example, I used some "Double == Double" statements on entity collision (on the 2D game engine part), or even on UI components collision (on the UI system part).

Comment: If you don't use any Double specific methods or null checks, null assignments, you can just change your variables from Double to double and it's going to work properly.

Comment: Why do you have to use the Double class instead of the _double_ primitive type ?

Comment: Btw if your program has "A LOT of math" as you said, you should change your Double to BigDecimal anyway (If you take care of the correct results)

Comment: When I started Java programming, I've always used Number classes instead of primitives. Maybe it would be good replacing all the Double instances with double, but it would be a pain on the ass - as I said before, it's 85,000 lines of code.

Comment: @JakubHr For general mathematics, including geometry, there is no magic to BigDecimal. For example, neither one third nor the square root of 2 can be exactly represented as a BigDecimal. BigDecimal is very good at exact representation of finite length decimal fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @nitind - this holds true for all objects, not just numbers. But to answer your question: Eclipse can't help you, since both == and equals() are valid and (depending on the use case) correct. Code analysers like Sonar and FindBugs might be able to help you find those, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's the difference between checking if two objects are equivalent vs. literally being the same object. I can show you two pictures both containing a 2002 Honda Accord sedan in metallic blue (.equals()), but they're not necessarily pictures of the same car (==). You have two Double objects holding values of 3.2, but ultimately you still have *two* objects.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/409507/java/java/Difference-equals